# Hugo website deployment to vercel, issue with submodule

Tags: deployment, vercel, hugo, hugo-theme

I am trying to deploy a Hugo static website to [vercel](https://vercel.com) via gitlab and having issues with theme submodule installation. Locally it is installed via `git submodule add https://github.com/dsrkafuu/hugo-theme-fuji.git themes/fuji` and it works.

When doing the deployment to vercel, apparently the theme is not fetched.

What was tried:

1. Deploying locally and pushing `public` directory with built htmls into the repo from where it was fetched by vercel, while  pointing Output Dierctory and/or root directory to public (and all other combinations of these parameters).
2. Using [vercel-CLI](https://vercel.com/docs/cli) to do the same.
3. Creating a shell script to trigger it in the install step of deployment (*npm vercel-install*) in vercel following [this](https://dev.to/beeinger/submodules-with-vercel-and-nextjs-4gml), but I get `Command "yarn vercel-install" exited with 128` or `Command "npm vercel-install" exited with 1`
4. Cloning the theme repo into the right place via `Install Command` parameter manually.

Do you know how a submodule can be properly fetched in vercel deployment?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, gave up and deployed in netlify.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this problem and it turned out to be not with git submodules but the default hugo version inside vercel is too old.

You can specify Hugo version by using `HUGO_VERSION` environment variable and set it to a recent release.

Possible causes:

- In a recent release, hugo changed the default configuration path from `config.toml` to `hugo.toml`, thus hugo inside vercel(default to v0.58.2) cannot recognize the config, and it won't know which theme you selected.