# Vercel is not loading/cloning Hugo theme git submodules

Tags: vercel, hugo

My Hugo site works perfectly when I manually install the theme added as a git submodule or run `git submodule update --init --recursive` after cloning my repo.

Now, it is just when I deploy it in Vercel and use the same command either as build command `git submodule update --init --recursive && hugo -gc` or install command as `git submodule update --init --recursive` the theme submodule never installs. In build command nothing shows up as executing however in install command it shows **Running "install" command: `git submodule update --init --recursive**

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out its cause and posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77661957/15081893

Original answer:

I recently faced this problem and it turned out to be not with git submodules but the default hugo version inside vercel is too old.

You can specify Hugo version by using `HUGO_VERSION` environment variable and set it to a recent release.

Possible causes:

- In a recent release, hugo changed the default configuration path from `config.toml` to `hugo.toml`, thus hugo inside vercel(default to v0.58.2) cannot recognize the config, and it won't know which theme you selected.